# How to list package versions available with conda

Tags: python, pip, jupyter, conda, conda-forge

Is there a way to see what package versions are available with conda? I am getting an error with jupyter but it was working before. Something like yolk?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can just type "conda search" which will give you something like the following.

```
$ conda search 
Fetching package metadata .........
affine                       2.0.0                    py27_0  defaults
                             2.0.0                    py35_0  defaults
                             2.0.0                    py36_0  defaults
alabaster                    0.7.3                    py27_0  defaults
                             0.7.3                    py34_0  defaults
                             0.7.7                    py27_0  defaults
                             0.7.7                    py34_0  defaults
                             0.7.7                    py35_0  defaults
                             0.7.9                    py27_0  defaults
```

Answer (score 180):

To search for a specific package, use: `conda search -f <package_name>`. For example, based on the question, to search all versions for "jupyter" package, you'll do: `conda search -f jupyter`. This will only return information about packages named "jupyter" exactly.

Source: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/search.html

Comment: Hmmm thanks but not sure about `-f` as the docs make no mention of it. In fact `diff <(condaw search -f jupyter) <(condaw search jupyter) |& wc -l` returns `0` for my version of conda: conda 4.7.10

Answer (score 45):

To list packages that are installed on your anaconda machine

```
conda list
```

This is to list all packages available for anaconda

```
conda search
```

Answer (score 23):

As an addendum, you can use the output of `conda search` to fine-tune the version of the package you need installed. E.g. in the list from the 'nasica88', there are three albaster 0.7.7 versions available with with different python versions. If you require e.g. albaster 0.7.7 with python 3.4, you install it as following:

```
$> conda install albaster=0.7.7=py34_0
```

So, the second `=` sign is your friend here.

Comment: And the `-h` output for `conda search` doesn't clarify the meaning of the two `=` signs, hence my new question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/57538225/257924

Answer (score 13):

If you know the name of the package you want to install search for all available versions of it. eg. for package pandas you will do the following

```
conda search pandas
```

and then install the version you want using

```
conda install pandas=1.0.2
```

Answer (score 8):

To get the version of certain package you can filter it by `grep` Like:

```
$ conda list | grep tensorflow
```

Result:

```
tensorflow                2.2.0           mkl_py36h5a57954_0  
tensorflow-base           2.2.0           mkl_py36hd506778_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.2.0              pyh208ff02_0
```

Answer (score 8):

To control specific channels, use `-c` option. For example:

```bash
conda search -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

The above will also [search in the channels listed in `.condarc`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/search.html), so to avoid that (and get results faster) one can use `--override-channels`:

```bash
conda search -c conda-forge --override-channels jupyterlab
```

To only show versions above a specific release, use `"{package}>={release}"`. For example:

```bash
conda search -c conda-forge "jupyterlab>=3.5"
```

Note that some shells (esp. Windows) do not like single quotes, so using double quotes is safer.

Finally, if you intend to use the output in a program, to avoid parsing the results one can use `--json`:

```bash
conda search -c conda-forge --override-channels --json "jupyterlab>=3.6"
```

This will return:

```bash
{
  "jupyterlab": [
    {
      "arch": null,
      "build": "pyhd8ed1ab_0",
      "build_number": 0,
      "channel": "https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch",
      "constrains": [],
      "depends": [
        "ipython",
        "jinja2 >=2.1",
        "jupyter_core",
        "jupyter_server >=1.16.0,<3",
        "jupyter_server_ydoc >=0.6.0,<0.7.0",
        "jupyter_ydoc >=0.2.2,<0.3",
        "jupyterlab_server >=2.19,<3",
        "nbclassic",
        "notebook <7",
        "packaging",
        "python >=3.7",
        "tomli",
        "tornado >=6.1.0"
      ],
      "fn": "jupyterlab-3.6.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.conda",
      "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
      "license_family": "BSD",
      "md5": "1a9cd36192678fc2175145c9103b95ff",
      "name": "jupyterlab",
      "noarch": "python",
      "package_type": "noarch_python",
      "platform": null,
      "sha256": "66da471830af4f5a7baa6229240c9dfe0fcc43bf20cc576067dab742bf5ec02e",
      "size": 5827178,
      "subdir": "noarch",
      "timestamp": 1675350928375,
      "url": "https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/jupyterlab-3.6.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.conda",
      "version": "3.6.0"
    },
    {
      "arch": null,
      "build": "pyhd8ed1ab_0",
      "build_number": 0,
      "channel": "https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch",
      "constrains": [],
      "depends": [
        "ipython",
        "jinja2 >=2.1",
        "jupyter_core",
        "jupyter_server >=1.16.0,<3",
        "jupyter_server_ydoc >=0.6.0,<0.7.0",
        "jupyter_ydoc >=0.2.2,<0.3",
        "jupyterlab_server >=2.19,<3",
        "nbclassic",
        "notebook <7",
        "packaging",
        "python >=3.7",
        "tomli",
        "tornado >=6.1.0"
      ],
      "fn": "jupyterlab-3.6.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.conda",
      "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
      "license_family": "BSD",
      "md5": "c7de31a5b57a9fc1aa4d3fb9993819c6",
      "name": "jupyterlab",
      "noarch": "python",
      "package_type": "noarch_python",
      "platform": null,
      "sha256": "8f7d234af44356633f8d418ed3001e814215ff09cedbec9583e3fb10fb7cc5e2",
      "size": 5354015,
      "subdir": "noarch",
      "timestamp": 1675434565845,
      "url": "https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/jupyterlab-3.6.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.conda",
      "version": "3.6.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To trim down the long and slowly loading `conda search` output to just the (latest) version(s) appropriate for your environment, you can use *MatchSpec* filters, as documented [here in conda Github repo](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/models/match_spec.py)

For example to get all available builds of `scikit-learn` pre-compiled for Python 3.11 from the free `conda-forge` channel, run this in your Linux terminal:

```
$ conda search "conda-forge/linux-64::scikit-learn=[build=py311*]"
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
scikit-learn                   1.1.3 py311h3b52e38_1  conda-forge
scikit-learn                   1.2.0 py311h67c5ca5_0  conda-forge
scikit-learn                   1.2.1 py311h67c5ca5_0  conda-forge
scikit-learn                   1.2.2 py311h103fc68_1  conda-forge
scikit-learn                   1.2.2 py311h67c5ca5_0  conda-forge
scikit-learn                   1.2.2 py311hc009520_2  conda-forge
scikit-learn                   1.3.0 py311hc009520_0  conda-forge
scikit-learn                   1.3.1 py311hc009520_0  conda-forge
```

Note that the most recent version is placed at the bottom of the list (they are sorted in chronological order), so it can be found using `tail -n1`, e.g.:

```
$ conda search "conda-forge/linux-64::scikit-learn=[build=py311*]" | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}'
1.3.1
```

Cautions:

- using `version` for narrowing down major and/or minor version is risky, because `version=1.*.*` would miss versions such as `1.1` or `1`,
- setting architecture (using `subdir` key) to `linux-64` can miss some useful Linux 64-bit packages, if they are stored in the `noarch` folder instead of `linux-64`,
- for some packages an older version of Python may be required (e.g. up to 3.9 for the "deprecated" `notebook`).

Answer (score 3):

I installed pip in conda, so `pip list` also works

Answer (score 3):

`conda list <pattern>` works too.

```bash
    (base) root@fb7969c44a12:/# conda list jupyterlab
    # packages in environment at /opt/conda:
    #
    # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
    beatrix-jupyterlab        2023.46.184821           pypi_0    pypi
    jupyterlab                3.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
    jupyterlab-git            0.41.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    jupyterlab-lsp            4.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
    jupyterlab-server         2.22.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    jupyterlab-widgets        3.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
    jupyterlab_pygments       0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 0):

example with cudatoolkit:

```
conda search -c nvidia cudatoolkit
```