# AttributeError: Object ParquetDataSet cannot be loaded from kedro.extras.datasets.pandas

Tags: python, pip, conda, kedro

I'm quite new using Kedro and after installing kedro in my conda environment, I'm getting the following error when trying to list my catalog:

Command performed: `kedro catalog list`

Error:

> kedro.io.core.DataSetError: An exception occurred when parsing config
> for DataSet `df_medinfo_raw`: Object `ParquetDataSet` cannot be loaded
> from `kedro.extras.datasets.pandas`. Please see the documentation on
> how to install relevant dependencies for
> kedro.extras.datasets.pandas.ParquetDataSet:

I installed kedro trough conda-forge: `conda install -c conda-forge "kedro[pandas]"`. As far as I understand, this way to install kedro also installs the pandas dependencies.

I tried to read the kedro documentation for dependencies, but it's not really clear how to solve this kind of issue.

My kedro version is **0.17.6**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kedro uses Pandas to load `ParquetDataSet` objects, and Pandas requires additional dependencies to accomplish this (see ["Installation: Other data sources"](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html#other-data-sources)). That is, in addition to Pandas, one must also install either `fastparquet` or `pyarrow`.

For Conda you either want:

```bash
## use pyarrow for parquet
conda install -c conda-forge kedro pandas pyarrow
```

or

```bash
## or use fastparquet for parquet
conda install -c conda-forge kedro pandas fastparquet
```

Note that the syntax used in the question `kedro[pandas]` is meaningless to Conda (i.e., it ultimately parses to just `kedro`). Conda package specification uses [a custom grammar called `MatchSpec`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734390/570918), where anything inside a `[...]` is parsed for a `[key1=value1;key2=value2;...]` syntax. Essentially, the `[pandas]` is treated as an unknown key, which is ignored.

Comment: Thanks Merv! After installing pandas properly into Kedro (kedro[name='pandas'] as well as installing pyarrow, I could list the catalogs. Tks

Answer (score 2):

Try installing using pip

```sh
pip install "kedro[pandas]"
```

As of now, conda doesn't support optional dependencies. Feature request for the same is submitted here https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7502

Also, in kedro docs its mentioned pip is recommended https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/02_get_started/02_install.html

> It is also possible to install Kedro using conda, as follows, but we
> recommend using pip at this point to eliminate any potential
> dependency issues, as follows:

Also, as @datajoely mentioned, you can also be more specific about which all dataset modules you need with the following.

```sh
pip install "kedro[pandas.ParquetDataSet]"
```

You can read more about kedro dependencies here https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/04_kedro_project_setup/01_dependencies.html?highlight=top-level#workflow-dependencies

Comment: You can also be specific with `pip install kedro[pandas.ParquetDataSet]` - I have an example here https://github.com/datajoely/modular-spaceflights/blob/260b209c24c7440342b41fb02f218d39c9115220/src/requirements.in#L9

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I went through Conda, because we are not using pip here in the project. However, I've seen an example with PIP that works in the way you proposed.