# Conda - search for package, specify Python version

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm trying to search for a package, specifying the *Python* version. I have tried:

```
# Find Python 2.7 packages for 'numpy'
conda search "numpy=py27_0" --info
No match found for: numpy=py27_0. Search: *numpy*=py27_0

conda search "numpy==py27_0" --info
No match found for: numpy==py27_0. Search: *numpy*==py27_0
```

How can I specify the Python version, e.g. `2.7`, `3.6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct mechanism to constrain Python version outside of running the actual solver. However, the major channels use the Python version (say 3.8) to generate a string (say `"py38"`) that is included in the *build string*. This can thus be used as proxy, by searching for constraints on the build string. For example, the following (equivalent) expressions should pick up all Python 2.7 builds of `numpy` in the configured channels:

```bash
## search all versions with 'py27' build string
conda search 'numpy=*=*py27*'

## alternative (MatchSpec) syntax
conda search 'numpy[build=*py27*]'
```

The first version must explicitly specify the version as unconstrained ("*"); the latter directly specifies the build constraint, with the unconstrained version implied.