# Conda install script installs wrong version and then doesnt update

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

Conda tells me that there is an update available, but when I try to update, it doesnt work. I run `conda update -n base -c defaults conda` and get the following notification:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.10.3
  latest version: 22.11.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.
```

I cannot find a github repo for anaconda. What is the issue here? Running `conda --version` confirms 4.10.3 is installed. I installed anaconda through the `Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh`, so definitely not 4.10.3.

Comment: `conda update <pkg>` means "update <pkg> to latest version *compatible with my other installed packages*", which is not strictly the latest version. So, there is something in the environment that is incompatible (e.g., Python version is too old). Using `conda install` can force Conda to explain itself (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75112666/570918).

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation:

```
#update the conda package manager to the latest version
conda update conda
#use conda to update Anaconda to the latest version
conda update anaconda
```

To update to a specific version of Anaconda, enter these commands:

```
#update the conda package manager to the latest version
conda update conda
#use conda to install a specific version of Anaconda
conda install anaconda=VERSION-NUMBER
```

Did you try these steps, including updating anaconda?