# How to specify g++ version when using conda install?

Tags: installation, anaconda, g++

I use the following command to install g++ in my conda enviroment:

```
conda install gxx
```

After installation, use g++ --version to check the version and got this output:

```
g++ (conda-forge gcc 12.2.0-19) 12.2.0
```

However my CUDA version is 11.3 which doesn't work with g++ 12.2.0. Below is the error when I tried to run sh ./make.sh according to this [repo](https://github.com/fundamentalvision/Deformable-DETR#compiling-cuda-operators):

```
RuntimeError: The current installed version of g++ (12.2.0) is
greater than the maximum required version by CUDA 11.3 (10.2.1). 
Please make sure to use an adequate version of g++ (>=5.0.0, 
<=10.2.1).
```

So my question is what is the conda command to install version 10.2.1 g++?

I tried the following commands and none of them are working:

```
conda install gxx-10.2.1
conda install gxx@10.2.1
conda install gxx==10.2.1
conda install gxx 10.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Were it available, the syntax would be:

```
conda install gxx=10.2.1
```

However, Conda doesn't build every version: that specific one [does not appear available](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gxx/files). It is possible for Conda Forge to [build out-of-sequence versions](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/updating_pkgs.html#maintaining-several-versions) via non-`main` branches. If you absolutely need that version you could [request it on the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/ctng-compiler-activation-feedstock/issues). However, that is a very complex feedstock and may have trouble getting a volunteer to contribute the time to modify the recipe.

Otherwise, you can look for something in the range using [the MatchSpec syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734390/570918):

```bash
## heed the usage of quotes
conda install 'gxx[version=">=5,<10.2.1"]'
```

which for me on **linux-64** platform resolves to `gxx=9.5.0`.<sup>**1**</sup>

---

<sub>**[1]** Note that I have `conda-forge` set as the default channel. If that is not the case for you, you may also require the argument `-c conda-forge`. Also, do not install this in a **base** Anaconda environment - there be dragons.</sub>