# Conda install package excluding specific build

Tags: conda

How do I exclude a specific version and build (and only that one) from being a candidate for `conda install`?

I need to `conda install` a `linux-64` package of `zstd` but the automatically selected `zstd=1.5.5=hc292b87_0` (from main) causes problems later on.

The theoretical goal specification would allow everything but the offending version and package, e.g.:

1. forbid version and build `1.5.5=hc292b87_0`,
2. allow versions after `1.5.5`,
3. allow version and package `1.5.4=hc292b87_0` (same build, different version; from main),
4. allow version and package `1.5.5=hfc55251_0` (same version, different build; from conda-forge).

Point 3 is not needed in my circumstances but would be educational.

Having given up, I actually run:

```
conda install --name base --channel conda-forge --yes mamba "zstd=1.5.5=hfc55251_0"
```

Both, [main](https://anaconda.org/main/zstd/files) channel and [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/zstd/files), supply 1.5.5 but only the conda-forge version (build `hfc55251_0`) currently does not result in failure.

Failed specifications so far:

1. `zstd=1.5.5!=hc292b87_0`: invalid specification
2. `zstd!=1.5.5=hc292b87_0`: installed `1.5.4=hc292b87_0`
3. `zstd!=hc292b87_0`: seems like `hc292b87_0` is understood as a version, installed `1.5.5=hc292b87_0`
4. `zstd!=*=hc292b87_0`: `*` seems understood like a literal version, installed `1.5.5=hc292b87_0`
5. `zstd>1.5.5|1.5.5=hfc55251_0`: installed `1.5.5=hfc55251_0`, looked good but checking with a lower version ..
6. `zstd>1.5.4|1.5.4=hc035e20_0`: I accidentally chose an osx-64 build here which `conda install` rejected. Together with 5. this indicated that the specification is not understood as ">1.5.4" OR "1.5.4=hc035e20_0" but instead as ">1.5.4" OR "1.5.4" for "hc035e20_0", so effectively `>=1.5.4=hc035e20_0`.

I am running conda 23.7.4. See also: [conda Package Match Specification](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/stable/resources/package-spec.html#package-match-specifications)

Comment: What is the failure?

Comment: I failed to find a specification for `zstd` that would install version 1.5.5 but not from build `hc292b87_0`, and that would also allow future `zstd` versions possibly including build `hc292b87_0`.

Comment: You mentioned that this specific build "*causes problems later on*" - what exactly are the problems? Have you reported them to Anaconda?

Comment: It is nice of you to approach the subsequent problem but I really want to stay on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the `build` and `version` specifications are independent, so I believe what you hope for - to only exclude a *combination* - is outside the grammar. However, you can more specifically exclude a build using [MatchSpec syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734390/570918):

```
'zstd[build!=hc292b87_0]'
```

While that will avoid some other builds (e.g., `main::zstd=1.5.4=hc292b87_0`), the hashes change rather frequently, so it should be a limited surface. That would at least accomplish what you were hoping that `zstd!=*=hc292b87_0` would cover.

Comment: `zstd[build!=hc292b87_0]` does not work and led to installation of `zstd=1.5.5=hc292b87_0`. I believe this is because [match_spec.py:_parse_spec_str Step 3](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/main/conda/models/match_spec.py#L647) needs `build=<build_spec>` first, i.e. a key-value pair; otherwise it has an empty `finditer`. I thought `zstd[build=!=hc292b87_0]` should work but currently leads to `PackagesNotFoundError` - channels `(conda-forge|pkgs/(main|r))/(linux-64|noarch)`. Will resume later.

Comment: Checking on the `_implementors` I saw that `build` uses `GlobStrMatch` which means no operators (e.g. "!=") allowed in spec ... but it allows regular expressions, and so can exclude the specific build. Ultimately, `"zstd[build='^(?!.*hc292b87_0).*$']"` worked (installed `zstd=1.5.5=hfc55251_0`). Found the format [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240365/1467307) where comments explain more.