# Conda: Possibility to set channel priority on package basis?

Tags: conda

Is it possible to set channel priority for a specific package only?
Say we want package Foo from channel Bar with highest priority, but no other packages from that channel. I'm thinking of something similar to ubuntu's apt pinning.
Is this doable with conda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this specification is given by the expression:

```bash
bar::foo
```

when specifying the package in either a YAML or in a `conda install` command. If the `bar` channel is not included as a channel to search (e.g., in the `channels:` section of a YAML or a `-c` argument), then only the `foo` package will be sourced from the `bar` channel.

You may further be interested in [more details about the full MatchSpec syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734390/570918).

Comment: What will happen if we update? Is the channel prefix still honored in that case, or would an update switch `foo` to another (per config higher-priority) channel?
I was aware this syntax exists, just not sure about its full capabilities. I was originally referring to `conda config --add channel_name`.

Comment: By using `bar::foo`, this sets exactly that as the explicit specification for all future solves. That is, you have defined this environment as having `foo` installed from the `bar` channel. If you want more control though, I'd suggested learning to work only from YAML and treat environments as immutable, i.e., always create new environments instead of mutating existing ones.