# Conda search for a specific package version

Tags: conda

I'm trying to search for a specific package version using Conda. From the docs:

```
Search for a specific version of a package:

conda search 'numpy>=1.12'
```

Returns the error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

 - 'numpy
```

It looks to be an issue with single quotes `'` - I have tried:

```
conda search numpy >= 1.12
* No output *
```

What is the correct syntax for conda search?

Comment: Which terminal are you using?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Using Miniforge Prompt, Windows 10

Comment: This might help also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73068535/10693596

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes don't work in every terminal, specifically not under windows. try using double quotes:

```
conda search "numpy>=1.12"
```